# UICollectionView removing an item issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a CollectionView where displays the photos from the camera roll, just like the default photo app of iPhone (one cell per photo)

I need to implement a delete functionality, so I successfully created a delete action. The problem is when I am trying to reload the data of the collection view.

To give an example I want to mimic the default's photo app behavior on delete.

Below I have the code which crashes. It is executed after successfully delete action.

```
func removeFromCollectionView() {
    let ip = self._collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    self._itemsCount? -= 1
    _collectionView.deleteItems(at: ip)

    _collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self._collectionView.reloadItems(at: ip)
    }, completion: nil)  
}
```

The error is:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Also, I have tried to wrap the code into

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { }
```

I tried to be explanatory let me know if you need more, does anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
*I did the below changes based on comments. The code does not crash but does not delete the photo*

```
func removeFromCollectionView() {
    let ip = self._collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    self._itemsCount? -= 1        
    _collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self._collectionView.deleteItems(at: ip)
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            print("finished")
            self._collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how you are calling method "removeFromCollectionView()"? Call this method from main thread.

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos , move the **_collectionView.deleteItems(at: ip)** to inside of the performBachUpdates first, second, obviously you are calling something from the background. BTW, why are you deleting objects and THEN trynig to reload them? That doesnt make any sense?

Comment: @Sneak Actually I want just to "refresh" the data fo the collectionview after I have deleted an item

Comment: I am calling the removeFromCollectionView() from a completionHandler, sounds like this is the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos You are doing it wrong. Delete the items in the performBatchUpdates, and in the completion, check if finished and do a reloadData on the collectionview instead after.

Comment: @Sneak I did the way you told, but it does not work

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos What I described is what should work. In your method you are trying to remove some cells and you try to reload them **after** they are removed already, that is a crash in itself. However, that doesn't solve the **threading issue** in your question, which is basically something you do in your collectionView methods/delegates/datsource/removeFromCollectionView , which is basically needed to go through your code to see where you are doing threading. Even if you dispatch on main, you reload a cell, but some function in that cell could do something on a background thread still.